# Updating a column when a new row is inserted in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This trigger is creating problem, i could not find out why.

```
CREATE TRIGGER initialpay 
   ON  table1
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @value char
select @value = '1000000' from inserted

    update table1 
    set table1.column1 = @value

END
```

When the new row is inserted, the whole column of all the rows is getting updated. I want to update only the newly inserted row.
Can anyone tell me what is the prob?

Comment: you have no `where` clause on the update

Comment: what is the id column from inserted?

Comment: in my table its `user_id`. should i add `where user_id = user_id`?

Comment: If this is the same for every user, why not just make it a default value in the table, rather than requiring the need for a trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming that there is only one row inserted. You need to make your trigger set-oriented, otherwise you will miss multiline insertions.

```
CREATE TRIGGER initialpay 
   ON  table1
   AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update t1
    set column1 = i.col
    from table1 t1
    join inserted i on t1.id = i.id

END
```

Comment: Where did `i.col` come from? Shouldn't you be setting `column1 = '1000000'`?

Comment: Maybe, but I assume it's an example. I don't think he really wants to update a literal value in his table. I don't think he really want to update all lines in table1, there is no WHERE clause. Anyway, not enough info about the real need.

Comment: Just thought I'd ask as `col` was not mentioned in the question. The OP asked "When the new row is inserted, the whole column of all the rows is getting updated. I want to update only the newly inserted row" so your answer is correct. Joining to the `inserted` table will update the newly inserted rows and is a set based solution for multiple inserts; no need for a `where` clause.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read it carefully enough. I just have a hard time understanding what is done in this trigger :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use like the following syntax:

```
 update table1 
 set table1.column1 = @value
 FROM inserted
 WHERE table1.id= inserted.id;
```